# A question on terminology

Tags: predicate-logic

I started reading a Mathematical logic book.I wondered what is a definition by abstraction as well axiom schemata.

Comment: Axiom schemata is a phrase used for an axiom that's really many axioms in one. Typically countably infinitely many axioms. For instance, if the axiom says "for any formula $\phi$...", then really, it's one separate axiom for each formula $\phi$. Therefore, since such a statement is not strictly _an_ axiom, it's called an axiom schemata.

Comment: what you mean by *countably infinitely*?

Comment: Perhaps I just meant "countably many". I just don't feel that that phrase rules out "finitely many", as in "the number is countably infinite", so I said "countably infinitely many". It's late, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: no worry. Thanks.